# How do I know whether I have Node.js and npm successfully installed on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Node.js with these instructions and it seemed successful:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Then I installed npm with these instructions:

```
sudo curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

The nodejs installation seemed to work without errors but the npm command gave me a lot of errors. But it seems like they are installed because when I test what version I have they both come up:

nodejs -v

v0.10.30

npm -v

1.4.21

So If this doesn't tell me that I have both programs successfully installed, which I assume I do not, how do I know?

Comment: your tests tell that both are installed.

Comment: What npm command did you try to run and what are the error messages?

Comment: @Mritunjay if you add that as an answer I will tick it as the right one :)

I have already used curl `https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` which ran without errors so now I can't test whether it did work. But if -v is enough to know that it is installed successfully then that is all I need at the moment. Thanks guys :)

P.s or should I do something to take away my sudo installation of npm?

Comment: @Kriss Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your tests tell that both or properly installed.

But you can try just type `node` in terminal & it should open a node shell, where you can check by running basic commands.

Answer (score 1):

Current distributions of node.js (including the one you downloaded) already include npm. So maybe installing npm manually is one source of your errors. Beware that usually you run "npm install" with the permissions of a regular user. There are only some npm-based utilities that are to be installed with root permissions and the '-g' (global) command line switch.

Answer (score 0):

On linux if you wish to install node.js and npm as yourself NOT root :

to start fresh remove prior node.js and npm installs as well as these :

```
~/.npmrc
~/.npm
~/tmp
~/.npm-init.js
```

create your ~/bin/ directory if not already created :

```
mkdir ${HOME}/bin
```

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

```
cd node-v0.10.30/

./configure   --prefix=${HOME}/bin/nodejs

make -j8
make install
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

```
export PATH=${HOME}/bin/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

define NODE_PATH so node can find dir for modules otherwise
npm install xxx will put newly installed module into dir in curr dir :

```
export NODE_PATH=${HOME}/bin/nodejs/lib/node_modules
```

do above AND use syntax :

```
npm install xxxxx -g
```

always use the -g for global which puts package xxxxx into $NODE_PATH

NOTE - nodejs install gives you npm as well :

```
ls -la ${HOME}/bin/nodejs/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it seems like most people are recommending the ppa:chris-lea/node.js based on what comes up when I search. Everyone seems to give different instructions of how to install Node.js. Do you care to elaborate why your method is better? THat would be much appreciated because this is all very confusing and it feels like I could have security or compatibility issues in the future if I do it one way as oppose to another..

Comment: I prefer my technique since it makes it explicit where all the globally installed modules go IE. into $NODE_PATH which is handy to peek at - plus no need to rely on a ubuntu repository getting updated before I can upgrade to latest release of node/npm I just download/configure/make/make install right on top of my previous install - plus there are no compatibility issues since above gives you both node + npm